# Creating new point based on distance of other points

Tags: qgis, distance, qgis-modeler, create

I work in QGIS 2.14.

I have a point layer, and I want to add points to that layer basing on the distances between the "old" point and the "new" point. 
I was doing it by creating buffors from each point, so far. But it is very time- and memory-wasting. Maybe there is a way to solve it in Modeler.
I want it to look like that:
I choose manually two (or three) points in my point layer, then I type the distances from each point to the new one and the name (and other atributes) of the new point. Result should be the new point in the place I want, added to that layer with atributes I wrote.

Comment: Is distance your ONLY rule ? What is the exact definition of your new point's location relative to the former one ? Is there a one - one relation between them ?

Comment: It's the only rule. I want to do something like this: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ds5LWtO_CB0/Tr_kEuFh1nI/AAAAAAAAALg/A2Y330LJLg8/s1600/Construction2.png
When I have point A and B and their distance to C. This is my base to put the C on my map.

Comment: So ... distance is not the only rule ... you give an example made of two points defining a third one (C) ... please be clear on what you're really expecting ... for example why is C located there and not on the other "circles" intersection ?